# webmail.send not working mvc

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, webmail

Im working on a webapp and currently creating the contact page. I've created a mail form in the view which is handled by de controller via HttpPOST. Anyway, for some reason the webmail.send doesn't work. Does anyone see what i'm doing wrong?

The controller only contains the code for the smtp settings and sending the mail.
This is the controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Contact(string firstname, string lastname, string email, string subject, string message)
    {
        try
        {
            //smtp settings
            WebMail.SmtpServer = "smtp.google.com";
            WebMail.SmtpPort = 587;
            WebMail.SmtpUseDefaultCredentials = true;
            WebMail.EnableSsl = true;
            //smtp username
            WebMail.UserName = "email@gmail.com";
            WebMail.Password = "password";
            //receiver
            string EmailTo = "email@gmail.com";

            //send mail
            WebMail.Send(to: EmailTo, subject: subject, body: message, from: email);
            return Content("mail send");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string errorMessage = ex.Message;
            return Content(errorMessage);
        }
    }
```

The view contains some contact info and a form. The contents of the form are submitted as paramters to the controller.
And the view:

```
<div id="contactWrapper">
<div class="pageTitle">
    <p><span>Contact</span>Do you have questions or remarks? Feel free to contact us.</p>
</div>

<div id="contact">
    <div id="contactImage">
    </div>

    <div id="contactInfo">
        <h1>Pencil Art</h1>
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <p>
            <span class="wmt">W:</span>www.pencilart.com <br>
            <span class="wmt">M:</span>info@pencilart.nl <br>
            <span class="wmt">T:</span>+(31)6 105 22 848
        </p>
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <p>
            Bloemdwarsstraat 1 c <br>
            1016 LL Amsterdam <br>
            Nederland
        </p>
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <p>
            Kvk-no: 3216 544 871 234
        </p>
    </div>

    <div id="contactForm">
        <form method="POST">
            <div id="inputBox" class="singlelineBox">
                <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" class="singleTextLineInput">
            </div>

            <div id="inputBox" class="singlelineBox">
                <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" class="singleTextLineInput">
            </div>

            <div id="inputBox" class="singlelineBox">
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email-Adress" class="singleTextLineInput">
            </div>

            <div id="inputBox" class="singlelineBox">
                <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" class="singleTextLineInput">
            </div>

            <div id="inputBox" class="multlinebox">
                <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value="Sent">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The from address has to be the same as the address of the account which you used to configure your SMTP.